# Где можно найти исходный код android lockscreen -а?

Tags: android, android-sources

Рыскаю по https://github.com/android?tab=repositories , но не могу найти

p.s. Интересует локер только из android 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LockPatternUtils.java 
Lock*.java
...

[link text](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget)
[link text](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/LockPatternUtils.java)

[link text](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/com/android/internal/widget/LockPatternUtils.java?av=f)
[link text](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/com/android/internal/widget/)

[link text](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/LockPatternUtils.java)
[link text](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/)

Answer (score 0):

с помощью  android sdk manager скачай sourse for android sdk - должен быть

Comment: А где из этого sourse сам локскрин находиться?

Comment: Поищи `grep`'ом

**P.S.** Не *sourse*, а *source* и не *находиться*, а *находится*

Comment: В такой куче всего и вся, как андроид, невозможно найти что-либо grep -ом

Comment: не соглашусь. найти можно.